# mysql vs mongodb cache/load balancing

Tags: mysql, mongodb, php, cache

I have a system where users can 'like' content. There will likely be many hundreds of these likes going on at once. I'd like it to be AJAX driven so you get an immediate response.

At the moment I have a mysql table of likes which contains the `post_id` and `user_id` and I have a 'cached' counter on the posts table with the total number of likes - simple so far.

Would I benefit in any way, from storing any of this information in mongodb to take the load off of mysql?

At the moment, I click like, and two mysql queries run - and `INSERT into likes` and an `UPDATE on posts`. If I'm in a large-scale environment in heavy read/write situation what would be the best way to go?

Thanks in advance :)